# message : "Illegal return statement" in httppost

Tags: api, http, ionic-framework

the response for the HTTP POST is working in POSTMAN API testing tool,
I am trying simply validate the username and password in the API HTTP POST

[image]

`rest.ts` code is below

```
            import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
            import { Http,HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
            import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
            import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
            import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
            import 'rxjs/add/operator/finally';
            import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';



            /*
              Generated class for the RestProvider provider.

              See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
              and Angular DI.
            */
            @Injectable()

            export class RestProvider {

              // apiUrl = 'http://localhost:54117/api/Employees/GetEmployeeByID/1'
              apiUrl = 'http://localhost:54117/api/Employees/CheckCredentials/obj/'
              debugger;
              constructor(public http: Http) {
                console.log('Hello RestProvider Provider');
              }


              login(body) {
                debugger;

                console.log('body is',body);
               return  this.http.post(this.apiUrl, body).map(resp => resp.json());
              }
```

Comment: which ionic / angular version is this?

Comment: Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.1.2

System:

   NodeJS : v8.11.4
   npm    : 5.6.0
   OS     : Windows 10

Comment: not the CLI... it will be in your package.json.

Comment: "version": "0.0.1",

Comment: {
  "name": "LoginWithSideMenu",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint"
  },